# RMagick install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

all! I have a problem when installing rmagick gem on CentOS 5.5 server. When I issued command:

```
gem install rmagick
```

I got:

```
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/bin:/bin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I have installed imagemagick with correct version, and I find Magick-config in /usr/local/bin and my PATH includes that dir. However, the rmagick gem installer just does not search that dir for Magick-config. What should I do?

By the way, I have another CentOS 5 machine installing ruby and rmagick successfully, and the latter has the Magick-config file in /usr/local/bin, too.

Comment: I made a soft link in /usr/bin to /usr/local/bin/Magic-config, and the problem is gone. It seems no better methods.

Answer (score 1):

did you installed Imagemagick? eg:

```
yum  install gcc gcc-c++ ImageMagick-devel ghostscript freetype-devel \ 
libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libpng10-devel libwmf-devel libexif-devel \
libtiff-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

See this brilliant post on how to fix it.  Just skip the last 3 lines as they are PHP related.

http://codercake.com/installing-imagemagick-6-6-9-7-and-imagick-for-php-on-centos-5-5-64-bit/#comment-39

Answer (score 0):

here the commend which I was used in my command prompt. Please check the version

```
gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1' --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q8/lib --with-opt-include=C:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q8/include
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac High Sierra - 10.13.4 - https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php

sudo port install ImageMagick

sudo gem install rmagick