# "rmagick" gem installation issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am having issue while trying to install "rmagick" gem on centos. Following is the output I am having. Can anyone please help me identifying **what package I am missing**? I have installed all mentioned another stack-overflow thread: [RMagick install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431707/rmagick-install-error)

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

After following suggestions, now I am getting this output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:194:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Output Of mkmf.log:

```
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.  -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6    -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib -lMagickCore-6.Q16      -L/usr/lib -lMagickCore-6.Q16    -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so when searching for -lMagickCore-6.Q16
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so when searching for -lMagickCore-6.Q16
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so when searching for -lMagickCore-6.Q16
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMagickCore-6.Q16
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
```

Output of  gem_make.out is same as the terminal output above.

Answer (score 140):

try installing

```
  sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
```

Comment: looks promissing, but only on ubuntu

Comment: Worked on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Sławosz here you are:
`yum install ImageMagick-devel ImageMagick`

Comment: Worked on CentOS 7 with yum. Thanks.

Comment: For MacOS, please see my answer below.

Comment: Worked on Mint 18.2 (Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 38):

This [ImageMagick 7 with RMagick 2.16 on MacOS Sierra Can't find MagickWand.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647979/imagemagick-7-with-rmagick-2-16-on-macos-sierra-cant-find-magickwand-h) works for Rmagick 2.16.

```
brew install imagemagick@6
brew link --force imagemagick@6
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you are using homebrew and having issues with ImageMagick7.

Comment: `brew link --force imagemagick@6` helped me to install gem dhash.

Answer (score 18):

The error message says:

```
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
```

It seems you missing no package at all, you just have to tell `pkg-config` where to find the `MagickCore.pc` file to build the extension. If you have installed the package `ImageMagick-devel` using `yum` the file should be inside the directory `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` or `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig` (depending on your architecture). Check with this command (from now I assume you are on a amd64 machine, if it's not the case replace `lib64` with `lib`):

```
$ find /usr/lib64/pkgconfig -name MagickCore.pc
```

If the file is there you just have to install `rmagick` with this command:

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/lib64/pkgconfig' gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Thanks. your suggestion worked. However, I am getting another output now(please check the edited question details). I am not sure what to do with the "Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details." . Also, do I need to install the development versions mentioned in the output?

Comment: Hi, yes, I just confirmed that do have this glibc-headers lib installed. any other clue?

Comment: added the output of mkmf.log file above. Please check if you can find any clue. I am new at these and linux too, so a lot lost, outputs are less meaningful to me :( . Also, if you can give me a descriptive guide link to install RMagick that I can follow from start again, it will be of great help too.

Comment: no, I didn't compiled any package from source. I have always installed the packaged libraries either using "yum install" or "gem install" . The answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355798/gem-install-error-with-rmagick?rq=1 , do you think that can be a similar case for me too? incompatible version of rmagick with imagemagick?

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 this is now PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'

Answer (score 8):

The problem is, as the error puts it,

> Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path

The solution is also suggested there:

> add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc` to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable

So,

1. Find *MagickCore.pc* location:

   ```
   sudo find / -name MagickCore.pc
   ```
2. If it is not found, probably ImageMagick is not installed on your system — then install it (Google how to do it, as it depends on the OS)
3. Save it to the ENV var like that (make sure to put the path found in step 1):

   ```
   PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
   ```
4. Retry installing RMagick

Comment: The `directory containing` means you have to remove filename to make it work. So `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`.

Comment: Definitely! Thanks, @sekrett

Answer (score 7):

For Mac with Brew, simply..

`brew install imagemagick`

Then `gem install imagemagick` will work smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you're missing any packages.  The error message is important:

> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
>   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

Several of the answers on [this superuser duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/361435/i-have-compiled-imagemagick-on-my-centos-and-rmagick-wont-install) give good advice.

Answer (score 1):

On debian (unstable) the correct packages needed to resolve this error were `libmagickcore-6.q16-dev`, `imagemagick` and `libmagickwand-6-headers`

I found them by using `apt-file search MagickCore.pc` and `apt-file search MagickWand.h`

Answer (score 0):

For windows users who run into this, and are 100% psotive that they have the devkit installed:

When installing, you will be presented this prompt
[image]

Choosing 1 is not enough. Just press enter (1 & 3) and that will install the devkit properly.