# RMagick Redhat 7.2 error: Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redhat, rmagick

I am deploying my Rails 4.2 application in Redhat Linux 7.2 version. I cloned 
my project and when I run bundle  install, I am facing Rmagick error. When I try to install it manually, I am facing errors as:

> [root@ip-172-xx-xx-xxx Project2]# gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'
>
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing rmagick:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.4/ext/RMagick
> ```
>
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20161020-28371-150wzyp.rb extconf.rb checking for Ruby
>   version >= 1.8.5... yes checking for gcc... yes checking for
>   Magick-config... no checking for pkg-config... yes checking for
>   ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes Package MagickCore was not found
>   in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing `MagickCore.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'MagickCore' found Package MagickCore was not found in the
>   pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing`MagickCore.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'MagickCore' found Package MagickCore was not found in the
>   pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing `MagickCore.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'MagickCore' found Package MagickCore was not found in the
>   pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing`MagickCore.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'MagickCore' found checking for stdint.h... yes checking
>   for sys/types.h... yes checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
>
> Can't install RMagick 2.13.4. Can't find MagickWand.h.
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>
> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.13.4/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.4 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.13.4/gem_make.out

I tried running:

```
`yum install ImageMagick` (Installed ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.21.amzn1.x86_64)
`yum install ImageMagick-devel` (It said 'No package found')
```

I tried this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774501/rmagick-gem-installation-issue) where we have 
to find MagickCore.pc, but I didn't found any MagickCore in my system.

Please help how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

ImageaMagick, as different other larger projects, installs the pkg-config pc.-files of project-internal libraries in the subdirectory specific to the project.

In case of ImageMagick, this is usually the path `/usr/lib/imagemagick6/pkgconfig/` instead of `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`.

An easy fix is provided by adding the directory to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable via

`$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib/imagemagick6/pkgconfig`

A different approach is using the CLI-option `--with-path` for pkg-config. So in your case:

`$ pkg-config --with-path=/usr/lib/imagemagick6/pkgconfig/`

However, this means touching the pkg-config command of your package installation, which may be not possible in the mentioned case.