# ImageMagick 7 with RMagick 2.16 on MacOS Sierra Can't find MagickWand.h

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick, macos-sierra

I upgraded to imagemagick-7.0.4-3.sierra and now my previously installed RMagck 2.16 fails. I checked for MagicWand:

`$ find /usr/local -name MagickWand.h
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.4-3/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/MagickWand.h`

So it seems to be there. Also I reinstalled and relinked pgk-config. Didn't help as well. Any ideas?

Comment: I temporary fix is to downgrade to the latest imagemagick6


brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/6f014f2b7f1f9e618fd5c0ae9c93befea671f8be/Formula/imagemagick.rb

Comment: it helped me a lot, thanks! so the solution is: `brew uninstall imagemagick`, then `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/6f014f2b7f1f9e618fd5c0ae9c93befea671f8be/Formula/imagemagick.rb`

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I have just encountered and solved this issue on a new Mac running Sierra. There seems to be no solution for ImageMagick 7 at this time.

1. Uninstall existing imagemagick if needed
2. Install version 6:

   `brew install imagemagick@6`
3. Since this is keg-only, you should then force-link it:

   `brew link --force imagemagick@6`

This installed imagemagick version 6.9.7-4 for me.

Afterwards, the gem then installed successfully. I am including the version numbers for future readers:

> Installing rmagick 2.13.4 with native extensions

Comment: I didnt find a solution for making rmagick to work with imagemagick v7, falling back to v6 works as described in this answer, thanks

Comment: I opened an issue: https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/265 Let's see if they add this to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. You're a champ.

Comment: had to run  `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` after the above steps. hope it helps others.

Comment: @Yunwei.W Are you sure you uninstalled other versions of imagemagick and that you definitely force-linked it?

Comment: Thank you! Worked great on Sierra

Comment: If you'd prefer not to load all of ImageMagick's binaries onto your PATH, you can also run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig`

Comment: I needed both --force AND --overwrite:
`brew link --force --overwrite imagemagick@6`

Otherwise this worked!

Answer (score 7):

dyson's solution didn't quite work for me. I found that in addition to installing `imagemagick@6`, I also need to install pkg-config and then set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

```
brew install imagemagick@6 pkg-config
PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'
```

Comment: I prefer this solution because I don't have to remove the global linking to the latest ImageMagick version.

Comment: @TheLazyLog I think the problem with other solutions is that they assume you have stuff like pkg-config installed – after some time of using homebrew, one will definitely wind up with pkg-config on their computer. I was setting up a fresh Mac so that assumption just wasn't true for me.